# Angular 7 Only arrays and iterables are allowed issue with the code

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display some json data and keep getting this error:

**ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'Leanne Graham'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed**

Here is the code:

The Data

```
{id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham"}
```

app.component.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let element of data">
    {{element.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  data = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.get_users_by_id(1);

  }

  get_users_by_id(id) {
    this.dataService.get_users_by_id(id).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      this.data = res;
    });
  }

}
```

And Finally the service part

```
get_users_by_id(id) {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/users/' + id);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If this is your data: `{id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham"}` ... then it is *not* an array and that is why you can't iterate over it.

Comment: you're most likely trying to iterate over an object. This is one reason why you shouldn't explicitly type parameters in delegate methods and instead type them from the method that returns them. What are you getting as part of the `HttpResponse`?

Comment: @joh04667 response is returning exactly this:  {id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham"}

Comment: exactly...objects aren't iterable, so you can't use them in an `*ngFor`. if you changed `this.data = res;` to `this.data = [res]`, it would work, but i don't know why you'd want to iterate over a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are just getting an *object*, not an array, try changing your code like this:

**Layout the structure of the returned data**

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

This defines the structure that the received data is mapped to.

**Retrieve the data into that structure (service)**

```
get_users_by_id(id) {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.baseUrl + '/users/' + id);
}
```

Notice the generic argument: `this.http.get<User>`. By specifying `User` here, we are telling the built-in `http` service to retrieve the data into that structure.

**Subscribe in the client (component)**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  data: User;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.get_users_by_id(1);

  }

  get_users_by_id(id) {
    this.dataService.get_users_by_id(id).subscribe((res: User) => {
      this.data = res;
    });
  }

}
```

Now, when the response is returned to the first function passed to the `subscribe` method, the data is already mapped to a `User`.

**Display the single user in the UI (template)**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    {{data.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then this does not really make sense as a list. Are you expecting the "get_users_by_id" to normally return more than one user?

Answer (score 0):

Do check out the  [keyvalue](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe.

Using `keyvalue` pipe:

```
<ul>
 <ng-container *ngFor="let element of data | keyvalue">
    <li *ngIf="element.key === 'name'">
      <span>{{element.value }}</span>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/keyvalue-pipe-uvovp7